# How to remove the /category/ from WP without plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

my website blog is http://hawaiiturtletours.com/category/blog/. This is the only category on the site. I would like to know how can I remove or overwrite the URL for this page only so the new one is http://hawaiiturtletours.com/blog. One of the most suggested solutions in this case to overwrote URLs with the settings /%category%//%postname%/ does not work in my case.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From the WordPress Codex:

> The Category base and Tag base are prefixes used in URLs for category
>   and tag archives, which look like this:

```
>  example.net/wp/category_base/category_name 
> example.net/wp/tag_base/tag_name
```

> The default values for these are category and tag. You can change them, but > > you can't remove them from the URLs altogether.

A blog isn't really a category. If you go to WordPress Settings > Reading you'll see the option "Front Page Displays:". Change it to a 'static page' and select a page to be your static front page. You may need to create it at this point. Then you'll want to create a page called "blog" and back in Settings > Reading change "Posts Page:" to be your "blog" page.

This will give you the desired URL hawaiiturtletours.com/blog

Comment: hanks for your comment. I was able to make it work but now there is a strange problem. When you go to hawaiiturtletours.com/blog the page automatically redirects to hawaiiturtletours.com/blog1. I dont know where this redirect comes from. Cant see anything in the .htaccess either. Is there a way to figure out why this page is redirected to hawaiiturtletours.com/blog1? thanks.

Comment: @Parlanchina You have to edit the permalink of your "Blog" page. You probably created more than one by accident so it added a 1 to make it unique. You can do this on the edit screen of the page itself.